# "Runtime error 91" when opening Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

So my code is to create a copy of a database by closing it, copying it with a new name, and then re-opening the original:

```
 Global appAccess As Object
 Sub Auto_Open()

 Dim OtherDB As Object

 sOther = "E:\6thFormExamples\"

 sName = "ActualDB.accdb"

 sFullPath = sOther & sName
 Set OtherDB = GetObject(sFullPath)
 OtherDB.Application.Quit

 sNewName = Format(Date, "d-mmmm-yyyy")
 Dim fso As Object
 Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 Call fso.CopyFile(sFullPath, sOther & "Backup" & sNewName & ".accdb", True)

 'Reopen DB

  Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
  accessApp.Visible = True

  appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase ("E:\6thFormExamples\ActualDB.accdb")
 'Application.Quit

 End Sub
```

Now I know the file path is correct as it finds it to close it the first time. The error I receive is:

> runtime error 91,  Object variable or With block variable not set.

but I can't work out which variable as any used work fine during closing and copying the database.
Running office and Excel 2010 if it makes a difference

Error appears on line

```
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic mishaps/mistake, you inverted the name of your variable `appAccess` and `Set accessApp`

Btw, if you already have an instance of Access already open, or to avoid having multiple instances, you should use :

```
    'Reopen DB
On Error Resume Next
Set appAccess = GetObject(, "Access.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

On Error Resume Next    

      appAccess.Visible = True
      appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase ("E:\6thFormExamples\ActualDB.accdb")
     'Application.Quit
```

Comment: You can use `Option Explicit On` at the top of your code to show a compiler error rather than a runtime error for times when you mistype a variable name.

Comment: Cant believe I didn't notice I had the variable name wrong thanks, also for anyone else with a similar problem the answer code runs brilliantly by checking if Access is already open

Comment: @p-k-y : Yeah don't worry about such a little mistake, I once spent 2 days going numerous time trough my code to finally find the exact same problem, 2 variables with very similar names! ;)